# Open icCube dashboard (with parameters) by clicking on an element

Tags: javascript, parameters, dashboard, iccube, iccube-reporting

How can I set an event on an icCube dashboard that opens another dashboard? (and that passes the selection parameters)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what you are trying to achieve? Does the 'Embedded Report' not cover what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For example, in dashboard 1 I set an event on Row click (e.g. 'country')   on a Table. When clicking on a country of that table, I want this click to open dashboard 2 with the selected country as a filter to dashboard 2

Answer (score 1):

icCube helped me on a similar request from my side to allow a "drill-to-a-URL when clicking on a row/column in a chart" question. You can modify this to set the URL to open another dashboard.

The following set-up opens a new browser tab with google searching for the row clicked in the chart and the setting of the year filter:

Steps:

1. Define one or more On Click events in your chart, for example: On Row Click --> event:"country";
2. Define a MDX Filter on e.g. Year, call it: "year";
3. In the Widget JS Hooks, set the "On Send Event";
4. Add and modify the following code (this code opens Google with your parameter):

```
/**
 * Tips:
 * type  - fired event type,
 * event - fired event object (same as first element of args array),
 * args  - list of arguments passed to fireEvent function
 * 
 * Function may return:
 *  - event - will replace first element of args
 *  - args  - will replace whole args array
 *  - false - will cancel event
 */
function(context, $box, type, event, args) {    
  let yearEvent =  context.reportingContext.eventMgr_._eventValues["year"];
  if (!event.isEmptyEvent() && yearEvent && !yearEvent.isEmptyEvent() ) {      
    let win = window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q="+ event.caption() + "+" + yearEvent.caption() , '_blank');
    win.focus();
  }
  return args;
}
```

**Result** (test)

When you click on e.g. country "Netherlands", with filter setting "2011" --> google opens with a search result for "Netherlands 2011".